# calculate day difference between two unix timestamps at boundary values

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix-timestamp, datetime-format

I have two timestamps created against dates 02/09/2014 11:30pm and 03/09/2014 12:00am.

There is only 30 minutes difference between these timestamps but as date has changed from O2 October to 03 October, it should be calculated as a day.

My code is

```
$current_time_zone = isset($_COOKIE['IANA_timezone_key']) ? $_COOKIE['IANA_timezone_key'] : "";
$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), timezone_open($current_time_zone));
$d2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), timezone_open($current_time_zone));
$d1->setTimestamp($row["transitions_date"]); // $row["transitions_date"] has timestamp value
$d2->setTimestamp($curr_transition_in_date); // $curr_transition_in_date has timestamp value
$diff = date_diff($d1, $d2);
$day_difference = $diff->days;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to print "1 day" for your case?

Comment: @sithu In above case it is returning 0 as day difference but It should be returning "1" day if date is different.

Comment: I think you should re-think your approach; if we expand upon your assertion that "as date has changed from O2 October to 03 October, it should be calculated as a day", you would have to also say that there is a year of difference between December 31st of year X and January 1st of year X+1. Saying that there is "a day" of difference means "a period of greater than or equal the duration of a single day."

Answer (score 1):

You could not expect your desired day difference from the returning object of [date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) as it is based on the actual time difference. The easiest way would be to adjust it yourself.

```
$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$d2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$d1->setTimestamp($row["transitions_date"]);
$d2->setTimestamp($curr_transition_in_date);

$diff = date_diff($d1, $d2);
$day_difference = $diff->days;

echo 'Actual output from date_diff: '.$day_difference; 
echo '<br>';
if($d2->format('H:i:s') < $d1->format('H:i:s')){
    $day_difference++;
}
echo 'Corrected output: '.$day_difference;
```

**[Demo 1](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wGtp9K)** for the different day, but same month and year.
**[Demo 2](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iTdBT8)** for the same day, but different month and year.
**[Demo 3](http://codepad.viper-7.com/73l8RO)** for the same output.

Comment: Don't think this will work, because your `if` statement will "fail", if you have same day, but different month/year.

Comment: And why do you convert timestamp again `date('d', timestamp)` when you already have an DateTime object?

Comment: @Glavić Check [this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lglMbP) and then you will get an answer.

Comment: @Glavić Yes, that's why I did not use DateTime object and use `date()` function again. I'm not sure why I got the error although `$d1` has the property `date`.

Comment: @Glavić, may be my answer is not complete for your 1st. I could update the answer, but you already did it in your answer. I'm not copying yours. Eventually, your answer has been completely different from your original one :)

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I think unclear topics should be settled in the comments first.

Comment: But really, fix this answer, because it has wrong examples in it. [This](https://eval.in/211233) is not 1 day difference. If you are using `DateTime` forget date() and strtotime() function, `$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));` >> `$d1 = new DateTime('today');` etc.